# Use variables in pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

So i need to get a word between 2 other words; and im using pattern and matcher.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello(.*?)GoodBye");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
```

In this example i'm getting the word between Hello and Goodbye and it works.
What i want to do is replace Hello and GoodBye bye variables such as:

```
String StartDelemiter = "Hello";
String EndDelemiter = "GoodBye";
```

How should write it in Pattern p = Pattern.compile(---); I Tried :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "{ "+StartDelemiter +" (.*?) "+EndDelemiter+" }"  );
```

But application crashes !!

Comment: "application crashes" => what exception? on what line?

Comment: `{` and `}` are regex metacharacters, so your pattern will not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `{` and `}` with backslashes, something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\{ "+StartDelemiter +" (.*?) "+EndDelemiter+" \\}"  );
```

The curly braces are Regex quantifiers

```
<pattern>{n}    Match exactly n times 
<pattern>{n,}   Match at least n times 
<pattern>{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```

Comment: Actually, you need _two_ backslashes before `{`